# How can I reset the Progressbar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-progressbar

I just made a Countdowntimer and a Progressbar :

```
public void button1_onClick (View view) {
mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
        i++;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(i);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        i++;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
        game_end();
    }
};

 mCountDownTimer.start();
}
 public void button2_reset_onClick (View view) {
   mProgressBar.setProgress(0); }
```

It is also working but when I try to start it a second time I get no animation ? It counts until 10 but I cannot see it on the Progressbar... How can I reset the Progressbar properly ? I allready tried to make i = 0 but it doesnt helped

Comment: mProgressBar.setProgress(0);

Comment: allready tried it but doesnt helped

Comment: Con you post your complete code?

Comment: You said you tried i=0, but I don't see it in the code form button2

Comment: It makes no diffrence with or without :/ The animation is not starting

Comment: Maybe your main thread gets too busy. Try running it in a new thread.

Comment: you mean resetting part or whole ? Can u make a example

Answer (score 0):

```
mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
if(i == 0) {
mProgressBar.setProgress(100);  
}
```

if you want your counter automatically restarts when it reaches 0 uses this. otherwise do the opposite

Comment: Are you sure you want to reset the progress bar? or do you want to reset the timer?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you dismissing the progress bar. That internally calls the reset function of the progress bar and that will reset it to 0 for you.

Comment: I dont understand what youre meaning :/