# Resume countdown in progress bar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that counts backwards. When show value 0 stop The countdown will be stopped. In my qestion how do resume countdown in progress bar. This code show progress bar with countdown.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setMax(progressStatus);


            while (progressStatus > 0) {
                progressStatus -= 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        secondTimeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progressStatus));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Try to use chronometer

Comment: or use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly this is what you want.

[How can I reset the Progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971627/how-can-i-reset-the-progressbar)

```
ProgressBar.setProgress(0)
```

Just set your Progress manually from 1..100

Comment: but  count 100 , 99, 98 ... , 1